TLS MySQL Connectivity not picked up
I am trying to configure TLS connectivity with MySQL on a CiviCRM instance.
However, I am encountering the following errors when trying to run any cv commands.
cv setting:get

<p>Initialization Error</p><p><pre>Array
(
    [callback] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; CRM_Core_Error
            [1] =&gt; simpleHandler
        )

    [code] =&gt; -24
    [message] =&gt; DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] =&gt; 16
    [debug_info] =&gt;  [DB Error: connect failed]
    [type] =&gt; DB_Error
    [user_info] =&gt;  [DB Error: connect failed]
    [to_string] =&gt; [db_error: message=&quot;DB Error: connect failed&quot; code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=&quot;&quot; info=&quot; [DB Error: connect failed]&quot;]
)
</pre></p>

Here is what I used for CIVICRM_DSN:
    define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://' . $civicrm_db_user . ':' . urlencode($civicrm_db_pass) . '@' . $civicrm_db_host . ':' . $civicrm_db_port . '/' . $civicrm_db_name . '?new_link=true&ca=%2Fetc%2Fssl%2Fmysql%2Fdatabase-certificate.pem&ssl=true');

Here is what I have tried using for Drupal in settings.php:
$databases = [
    'default' => [
        'default' => [
            'database' => $drupal_db_name,
            'username' => $drupal_db_user,
            'password' => $drupal_db_pass,
            'host' => $drupal_db_host,
            'port' => $drupal_db_port,
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => '',
            'driver options' => array(
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/etc/ssl/mysql/database-certificate.pem',
          ),
        ],
    ],
];

I have confirmed that the certificate is accessible and has the right permissions. I am also able to connect to the database with TLS using mysql-client.
I have also tried configuring the DSN without the ca option and leaving in ssl=true, but this makes it that CiviCRM is accessing the site without TLS.
Are there other places in the configuration that I can use or attempt or are there misconfigurations in my setup?

Adding in environment versions for reference.
Environment Versions:
MySQL: 5.7.44
PHP: 8.0.27
Drupal: 7.98
CiviCRM: 5.51.3
cv: 0.3.58

One challenge here is that we don't see internal warnings about MySQL-SSL processing. It may take some looking to find the best way to fix that, but for now -- here's a crude patch to get more debug info: https://gist.github.com/totten/a85d6ad62c1b82f660878a46fd18c6c8

Clarifications:
(1) Does Civi's web UI work for you with MySQL-SSL? Is the problem limited to cv-CLI?
(2) Does Drupal CLI (drush) work? Which version?
(3) Are web UI and CLI running the same binaries/builds of PHP? (e.g. same version, same distro/container)
(4) When calling cv, does it make a difference to switch bootstrap vars?

Another tip: For the cv command that fails, enable verbose output (cv setting:get -vvv)

The code to use ssl was never finished and doesn't work for scripts. You could try reviving some variation of https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/18125.

can I ask if I can request for a Gitlab issue to be opened for this?

There is a gitlab https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1926, but without someone either funding a consultant to finish it or doing it themselves it will probably just stay half finished.
